# Using Analytics and the Shopify App store

Tags: google-analytics, shopify

When setting up a Shopify App for presentation in the App store there is a text field for entering an Analytics account ID. I entered my old Analytics ID for an App, and then waiting some time before examining the results. When I logged into my Analytics account, sure enough there was a pretty line graph showing the visits from the App store patrons.

It showed me hundreds of people from the USA visited the App but nothing else.

Could someone with knowledge of Analytics suggest a couple of simple ways to get some value out of this feature? Perhaps some tips on how to configure Analytics to reveal something interesting about the visits?

Answer (score 2):

Things you can try to “move some needles”:

- Change the app name, copy or app banner on the short description. This intervention will affect the visits number you’re looking at.
- Change the copy, video, or selling points on the app listing page. This intervention, combined with watching your visits:install rate tells you about conversion rate.

Answer (score 0):

The most interesting thing for these types of listings is the referring sites, in my opinion. This will let you know how people are getting to your app and where you might be able to improve exposure.

Comparing referring sites to outcomes such as installs and reviews would also be useful because you can see how people who actually install the app get there, and the same thing with reviewers. Setting up goals in google analytics will help you track these things.